# Running a motor for a 3 seconds continuously with and without interrupt

Tags: arduino-nano, motor, interrupt, timers, ir

I have interfaced a dc motor and IR sensor to my nano. The DC motor is supposed to run only if the IR sensor detects an obstacle. Now, I'm trying to get the motor to turn off if continuously obstructed for 3 seconds, and exit the interrupt (in case of the first code with interrupt), and again wait for the sensor to go low again (falling edge). I have implemented this using millis(), but the code doesnt seem to be working consistently, as the timing seems to have gone for a toss (random behavior; sometimes it keeps running continuously and sometimes it stops) . Can anyone on this forum please review it and suggest me a correction. Also, would it be possible to use a LOW trigger instead of falling edge to achieve this ?

```
#include <LowPower.h>


const int out1 = 5; //motor
const int IRSensor = 3; // connect ir sensor to arduino pin 6
const int LED = 6; // conect Led to arduino pin 9
const int Switch = 2;
const int Mspeed = 175;//0-255
const int Mtime =1500;//500-1000
int statusSensor=1;
int switchSensor=1;
unsigned long prevTime;
volatile int count =0;
volatile int count1=0;
volatile int count2 =0;
volatile int count3=0;
volatile int buttonstate=0;
volatile int lastbuttonstate=0;
volatile bool flag=false;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(out1,OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(out1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IRSensor, INPUT); // sensor pin INPUT
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT); // Led pin OUTPUT
  pinMode(Switch, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(IRSensor),IRinterrupt,FALLING);
}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_FOREVER , ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF); 
  delay (100);
  if (flag==true){
  //Serial.println("true");  
  switchSensor = digitalRead (Switch);
  //Serial.println ("zloop");

  statusSensor = digitalRead (IRSensor);
  //Serial.println (statusSensor);
  if (count1==1) 
  { prevTime = millis();
    Serial.println(prevTime);
  }
  if (millis() - prevTime >= 1000) 
  { doSomethingElse();
    Serial.println("going to else");
  }
  }
  //prevState = digitalRead(IRSensor);
  doSomething();



}

void IRinterrupt(){

   flag=true;
  }

void doSomething(){
  buttonstatus();
  if (statusSensor == 0 and switchSensor == 0 and count3==0){

     analogWrite(out1,Mspeed);
     //digitalWrite(out1,HIGH);
     count1=count++;
     Serial.println(count);
     digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }
   else if (statusSensor == 0 and switchSensor == 1) {

      //digitalWrite(out1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      analogWrite(out1,0);
      count=0;
      count1=0;
      prevTime = millis();
      }
   else if (statusSensor == 1 and switchSensor == 0) {

      //digitalWrite(out1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      analogWrite(out1,0);
      count=0;
      count1=0;
      prevTime = millis();
      }
    else {
      //Serial.println ("ir high");
      //digitalWrite(out1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      analogWrite(out1,0);
      count=0;
      count1=0;
      prevTime = millis();
      buttonstatus();
      }
} 
void doSomethingElse(){


      //Serial.println ("ir high else");
      analogWrite(out1,0);
      count=0;
      count1=0;
      prevTime = millis();
      count2++;
      count3=count2;

      //analogWrite(out1,0);
  }

void buttonstatus(){
  buttonstate=digitalRead (IRSensor);
   if (buttonstate != lastbuttonstate) {
    // if the state has changed, 
    if (buttonstate == LOW) {
      count3=0;
    }
    delay(50);
   }
   lastbuttonstate = buttonstate;
}
```

I have written another piece of code without interrupts. How do I achieve the same timing part for this too ?

```
int out1 = 5; //motor
int IRSensor = 3; // connect ir sensor to arduino pin 6
int LED = 6; // conect Led to arduino pin 9
int Switch = 2;
int statusSensor=1;
int switchSensor=1;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(out1,OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(out1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IRSensor, INPUT); // sensor pin INPUT
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT); // Led pin OUTPUT
  pinMode(Switch, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  switchSensor = digitalRead (Switch);
  //Serial.println (switchSensor);

  statusSensor = digitalRead (IRSensor);
  //Serial.println (statusSensor);
  delayStart = millis();
  //Serial.println ("ir interupt");

   if (statusSensor == 0 and switchSensor == 0){
     Serial.println ("ir low");
     analogWrite(out1,120);
     digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
   }
      else {
      Serial.println ("ir high");
      analogWrite(out1,0);

      }

}
```

EDIT: I have now successfully implemented the code (without interupts) with timing part in the code below.Also, I have updated the first code in the post with interrupts, but I am not able to get the timing part working. Can, someone please help me how timing can now be done with interrupts, so that the arduino nano is in sleep, until it receives a falling edge on the interrupt pin from the IR sensor, so that it can process the next part. Doing so I believe I would save power consumed since its on all the time.

```
const int out1 = 5; //motor
const int IRSensor = 3; // connect ir sensor to arduino pin 6
const int LED = 6; // conect Led to arduino pin 9
const int Switch = 2;
const int Mspeed = 175;//0-255
const int Mtime =1500;//500-1000
int statusSensor=1;
int switchSensor=1;
unsigned long prevTime;
volatile int count =0;
volatile int count1=0;
volatile int count2 =0;
volatile int count3=0;
volatile int buttonstate=0;
volatile int lastbuttonstate=0;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(out1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IRSensor, INPUT); // sensor pin INPUT
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT); // Led pin OUTPUT
  pinMode(Switch, INPUT_PULLUP);
}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(100);
  switchSensor = digitalRead (Switch);
  statusSensor = digitalRead (IRSensor);
  if (count1==1) 
  { prevTime = millis();
    Serial.println(prevTime);
  }
  if (millis() - prevTime >= Mtime) 
  { doSomethingElse();
    //Serial.println("going to else");
  }
  doSomething();

}

void doSomething(){
  buttonstatus();
  if (statusSensor == 0 and switchSensor == 0 and count3==0){

     analogWrite(out1,Mspeed);
     //digitalWrite(out1,HIGH);
     count1=count++;
     Serial.println(count);
     digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }
   else if (statusSensor == 0 and switchSensor == 1) {

      //digitalWrite(out1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      analogWrite(out1,0);
      count=0;
      count1=0;
      prevTime = millis();
      }
   else if (statusSensor == 1 and switchSensor == 0) {

      //digitalWrite(out1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      analogWrite(out1,0);
      count=0;
      count1=0;
      prevTime = millis();
      }
    else {
      //Serial.println ("ir high");
      //digitalWrite(out1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      analogWrite(out1,0);
      count=0;
      count1=0;
      prevTime = millis();
      buttonstatus();
      }
} 
void doSomethingElse(){


      //Serial.println ("ir high else");
      analogWrite(out1,0);
      count=0;
      count1=0;
      prevTime = millis();
      count2++;
      count3=count2;

      //analogWrite(out1,0);
  }

void buttonstatus(){
  buttonstate=digitalRead (IRSensor);
   if (buttonstate != lastbuttonstate) {
    // if the state has changed, 
    if (buttonstate == LOW) {
      count3=0;
    }
    delay(50);
   }
   lastbuttonstate = buttonstate;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108619/discussion-on-question-by-user3796354-running-a-motor-for-a-3-seconds-continuous).

Answer (score 0):

I often use a timer loop to read sensors. I've attached some code, which compiles, however I don't have the sensor.

BTW. I am assuming it is a single shot IR sensor that returns 0 if something is detected.

```
int out1 = 5; //motor
int IRSensor = 3; // connect ir sensor to arduino pin 6
int LED = 6; // conect Led to arduino pin 9
int Switch = 2;
int statusSensor=1;
int switchSensor=1;


unsigned long IRMillis;
int IRInterval = 100;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(out1,OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(out1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IRSensor, INPUT); // sensor pin INPUT
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT); // Led pin OUTPUT
  pinMode(Switch, INPUT_PULLUP);
  IRMillis = millis();
}

void loop() {

   updateIR();

   switchSensor = digitalRead (Switch);

   if ((statusSensor == 0) && (switchSensor == 0)) {
     IRInterval = 3000; // 3 seconds
     statusSensor = 1;
     Serial.println ("ir low");
     analogWrite(out1,120);
     digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
   } else {
     Serial.println ("ir high");
     analogWrite(out1,0);
   }
}

void updateIR() {
  if (millis() - IRMillis > IRInterval) {
    //continue
  } else {
    return;
  }
  IRMillis = millis();
  IRInterval = 100;
  statusSensor = digitalRead (IRSensor);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it returns a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your interrupt code looks reasonable, except that once you set flag to true you never set it back to false again. You need a way to identify the the IR sensor is no longer active.

Perhaps change your interrupt to fire on a change of state and set the flag to true when it switches to LOW (like it does no) and false when it switches back to high? I'd need to know more about your IR sensor to tell you exactly what to do, but I can tell you that the way your coe is currently written, once you detect the first falling edge on the IRSensor pin, your flag will switch to true and never change back to false.

I also don't understand what all the if/else if/else if logic is supposed to do, so can't really tell if you have any coding errors there.

Comment: I'm using an IR sensor which goes low only when an obstacle is detected. There is also float switch (switchsensor) which when goes high (tank being empty), the motor is supposed to go off and turn on an LED. That is why multiple if else statements are there. The same code without the interrupt part (flag) works fine, wherein the motor stops if continuously running for 1.5 seconds. But with interrupt in place, the timing part doesn't work.

Comment: Again, your code sets flag=true in the interrupt code, but never sets flag=false. That is wrong.